# How to format Mongoose debug output - pretty print

Tags: node.js, console, mongoose

How can I make Mongoose debug output look pretty in console? Currently the output is displayed on one line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is something I put together, maybe somebody will find it useful.

Install colors module for node.js (this is optional):
    `npm install colors`

Then in your file:

```
var colors = require('colors');

mongoose.set('debug', function (collectionName, method, query, doc) {
  console.log(
    'Mongoose: '.cyan + 
    collectionName + 
    '.' + 
    method + 
    ' (' + 
    JSON.stringify(query, null, 2) + ')');
});
```